# Field Overflow when column values contain space

Tags: etl, oracle-data-integrator, data-integration

I have a simple mapping to read data from a DB table onto a CSV delimited file using ODI(11g/12c).
Certain fields are having values with words separated by spaces, like "United States of America".
When the data is generated in CSV,I see that "United" is in one column, "States" is in the next column and so on. In other words there is an overflow of data in spite of the delimiter being set to ",".

IKM: SQL to File Append.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: How are you viewing the csv file - in a text editor or in something like Excel? If in Excel (or similar), try opening it in a text editor and see how it is actually formatted. Is ODI generating the file incorrectly or is it being interpreted incorrectly when being read?

Comment: @NickW,I had found out the root cause of why this was occurring. One of the columns had certain values separated by commas(','),which is why each value separated by a comma was considered as a separated column when viewed in Exce l. I resolved the issue by having the commas replaced with another delimiter(that is different from the file delimited that is, comma).